# Read XML file from php

Tags: php, xml

I have an issue reading this XML data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <VERSION>2.0</VERSION>
    <MESSAGES>
        <MESSAGE>
            <SEND_DATE>2014-02-26</SEND_DATE>
            <ENTITY_ID>7002</ENTITY_ID>
            <RECIPIENT_NUM>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM>
            <MESSAGE_PARAMS>
                <DEN_SURNAME>Roze</DEN_SURNAME>
                <APPT_DATE>27/02/14</APPT_DATE>
                <APPT_TIME>09:00</APPT_TIME>
            </MESSAGE_PARAMS>
        </MESSAGE>
        <MESSAGE>
            <SEND_DATE>2014-02-26</SEND_DATE>
            <ENTITY_ID>7002</ENTITY_ID>
            <RECIPIENT_NUM>xxxxxxxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM>
            <MESSAGE_PARAMS>
                <DEN_SURNAME>Roze</DEN_SURNAME>
                <APPT_DATE>27/02/14</APPT_DATE>
                <APPT_TIME>09:00</APPT_TIME>
            </MESSAGE_PARAMS>
        </MESSAGE>
        <MESSAGE>
            <SEND_DATE>2014-02-26</SEND_DATE>
            <ENTITY_ID>7002</ENTITY_ID>
            <RECIPIENT_NUM>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM>
            <MESSAGE_PARAMS>
                <DEN_SURNAME>Roze</DEN_SURNAME>
                <APPT_DATE>27/02/14</APPT_DATE>
                <APPT_TIME>09:00</APPT_TIME>
            </MESSAGE_PARAMS>
        </MESSAGE>
    </MESSAGES>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I have a `<MESSAGES>` tag containing several `<MESSAGE>` tags containing different values. I am currently using this code to read the values inside each `<MESSAGE>` tag.

```
$dr_name=$xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->MESSAGE_PARAMS->DEN_SURNAME;
$apt_date= $xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->MESSAGE_PARAMS->APPT_DATE;
$apt_time= $xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->MESSAGE_PARAMS->APPT_TIME;
```

I am getting only the values for the first `<MESSAGE>` tag.

How can I read all the `<MESSAGE>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simplexml object was returning the first record (0). So in your code you need to loop the Messages->message tag to reach them all.
You can use this code to fetch all messages:

```
$file = 'data.xml';
$oXml = simplexml_load_file($file);
if($oXml){
    if(count($oXml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE) > 0){
        foreach($oXml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE as $m){
        echo 'Sent: '.$m->SEND_DATE.'<br />';
    echo 'ID: '.$m->ENTITY_ID.'<br />';
    echo 'ID: '.$m->RECIPIENT_NUM.'<br />';
    echo 'Surname: '.$m->MESSAGE_PARAMS->DEN_SURNAME.'<br /><hr /><br />';
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also explain why your answer works and what the problem was

Comment: @andyb The problem was simplexml object was returning the first record (0). So in your code you need to loop the Messages->message tag to reach them all.

Comment: It's not my code :) I commented because good answers should explain why and share the knowledge, rather than just providing a block of code to use. You can edit your question your description if you want.

Comment: Cool. Here is a `+1` for you